# How plausible would a planet-sized theme park be?

Tags: science-based, technology, science-fiction, corporations

In my scifi lore, there is a giant theme park built for larpers, cosplayers, and furries(not antromorphic animal species, but the people who dress up and like the style), their target audiences. The way it functions is a bit similar to WestWorld, but is more towards the high medieval fantasy genre, and some areas are more like Jurassic Park. The park is built on a far away planet that is capable of sustaining earth life. Due to being a monopoly on that planet, I thought about how big the park can be built due to no other buildings and established buildings. If there was an empty planet, could an entire theme park be built on all of it, or at least most of the landmass or continent?

Note to mention:

- This is the distant future
- The park is backed by big investors, including big government officials and bankers
- The only non-theme park buildings that exist are just the first colony, the spaceship station port, some security stations, hospitals, and fire stations, and the headquarters branch center
- There is an equal amount of both landmass and ocean
- The majority of the products imported are from the company
- The company owns the planet, and they do not have to follow many government regulations and laws

Comment: I honestly don't get the point of the question. Could you tell us what the worldbuilding issue is, the problem to solve - else this is just a yes/no opinion-based question with no way whatever for anyone to decide what the right answer is except with a blindfold and a pin.

Comment: The company goes ahead and builds it: yes. The galactic council planning department visits, doesn't like it: no. The food and supplies are imported: yes. The local systems impose an embargo because they prefer Disney: no. What's the problem to solve here?

Comment: Plausible is a highly subjective metric more a function of the ability of a writer to sell an audience than it is a specific answerable question about establishing some fact of your world.

Comment: The answer by Postlim Fort is providing some of the additional parameters that need to be specified.  The other huge gap is why a whole planet?  Is it 10,000 duplicated medieval Disneyworlds or is every section unique?  If all unique, what onplanet transport is available to get between attractions?  Who are the customers, how much money and time do they have, why should they come here instead of going somewhere on their own planet?  Otherwise this is another ideas-generation question which will be closed.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 it is not multiple theme parks but rather multiple zones and sections. While in its first years, many of the areas were generic or looked the same, but now they are more different. In addition, the target audience are layperson, cosplayers, and furries, mentioned above.

Comment: @Crafter let's just unpack one word from that comment - what do you mean by "furries" in a futuristic sci fi context?  Do you mean "standard" humans dressing up in animal costumes or genetically modified people?  What is the user experience the typical furry is looking for - a few hours in a themed area and then teleport home OR a number of days spent in the area but staying in a modern 5-star hotel each night OR a month of immersive living in a fully simulated humanoid feline medieval setting? I assume you have a vision for this, but we don't know it.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 what I meant was people who like the style and dress up. I also edited the question to fix future problems. And I misspelled larpers

Comment: The simple answer is “No” and no more detailed answer is really possible. If Earth had one single space port in London, how do patrons get to Japan? No airports? No hotels? Where do they buy their building materials from? No construction industry? No cement factories? Steel plants? No shipping ports to move rollercoasters from London to Miami? Who handles all the trash and waste? No landfills or sewage plants at all? Someone gets hurt, no hospitals? No police protection? Who puts out fires when equipment fails? A planet with no infrastructure is always not plausible.

Answer (score 12):

### You need some non-park areas

Staff need to live somewhere.
Maintenance gear and spare parts take space.
You need a spaceport.
You need sewage and water infrastructure.
You need a hospital. You need fire stations.

On earth, these things are all outside the park. On a park planet, they need to be on the planet, hence in the park. This is the case for every service that is normally based outside the park.

If you have interplanetary teleportation, you may be able to deal with any or even all of these problems with some portals and minimal dedicated space (yes, even sewage...some unlucky planet is All The Poo From Disney Planet planet).

Comment: Could most of this be underground? Similarly to how Westworld's facilities are all underground and there are lots of hidden maintenance exits around the park.

Comment: Hard to do the spaceport that way. The rest, why not?

Comment: I guess you could have a spaceport sticking out (with theming around it to cover it up), but that would just be one building. The rest of the planet could still be park.

Comment: @MatejDrobnic Not quite, you'll need regional transport too, or multiple spaceports. No good landing in Australia if you like rollercoasters but they're all in Europe. Of course, train stations can be underground.

Comment: You also need those doohickeys where food comes out of the ground.

Comment: @Daron You can do that under a rollercoaster.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 But the loud noises might frighten the ponies.

Answer (score 8):

**Plausible? Yup. The way you're thinking about it?... Not so much.**

Of course it's plausible. SciFi has had pleasure planets since the dawn of writing. That's not the problem.

Some of your conditions don't make sense. Unless you have a galactic empire with near instantaneous travel and very instantaneous communication, you won't have "corporations" the way you're thinking. That's very today-Earth where enough governments are larger than global corporations that they're still playing second-fiddle.

1. Your corporation owns and operates *an entire planet.* That's indistinguishable from a government. Your planet will have every conceivable job, from child care and janitorial through education and professional white-collar to government and administration. You'll have homes and factories and offices and grocery stores, and movie theaters.... People will be born, live and die having never left your planet. The fact that the letters "Inc." appear after the government's name has no practical meaning.
2. And that means your government will be subject to espionage, sanctions, and war just like any other government. Where there be no rules, there be no rules, and all the other <s>corporations</s> governments in the galaxy will treat you as they are treated — according (or not) to <s>corporate agreements and contracts</s> treaties.
3. As for following laws — you had better believe corporations follow laws, even if they're their own! A planet full of amusement park rides? The logistics in materials, food, people... it's staggering! You'll have policies, procedures, regulations, directives, statutes, mandates, ordinances... and *laws...* running out your ears. Your corporation's legal department might be second only to the finance department. Heck, I've worked for corporations where their employee policy "manual" had *volume numbers.* Yours will require a library.
4. In other words, you seem to have a low appreciation for the need for administration. Your bureaucracy will number in the millions. You'll have police and spies and a military and tax collectors and firemen and hospitals and schools and libraries and places-where-people-can-complain and every other trapping of traditional government. The only labor force larger than your bureaucracy will be ride operators. And the only distinguishing factor between your corporation and a government is that you might (maybe) be able to stop those ride operators from forming a union.

Look at our planet and what it takes to *manage its day-to-day affairs.* Your planet won't be any different. Other than the organization in charge will have something like "Inc." at the end of its name.

A rose by any other name still stinks like a kettle of rotting fish.

Answer (score 7):

It would be fairly plausible if your world has the following:

- FTL is cheap, safe, and fast. Even poor people should be able to take the bus over to your theme park and be back home for dinner.
- All over your planet you will find infrastructure to quickly access the different parts of your park. (Preferably hidden - think space elevators, and underground high speed rail.)
- The theme park workers have to live as well. Those bastards keep demanding to see their families. Not to mention having vacation, or workers' rights. The orbital/underground facilities will be vast, even if they all commute each day to the nearest Eucemenopolis.
- It must be situated in a state. That is to say, it has to abide by government regulations. That state will provide the safety and stability the people need before they think about visiting a theme park. (You don't find many running theme parks in war-zones/frontier settings.)

Missing any single one of these will render it abandoned or un-profitable at best.

Comment: FTL also has to be cheap because if the entire landmass is given over to theme parks, you'll need to import fifteen thousand tonnes of waffle cones a day, to say nothing of popcorn.

Comment: Additionally: it's only plausible if the galactic population is quite large (trillions).  If you have a lightly populated galaxy, there's no reason to make over the entire planet -- you'd just do one small continent or large island.

Comment: On the bright side, you can have plenty of trees and flowers in the park to handle the oxygen demands.